# openldap, ldapsearch without bind from outside

Tags: openldap

If I look in my openldap logfile, I always find 3-4 times per day the following lines (olcLogLevel: 256; IP replaced):

```
Oct 17 23:44:40 debian slapd[674]: conn=1011 fd=14 ACCEPT from IP=______________ (IP=0.0.0.0:389)
Oct 17 23:44:40 debian slapd[674]: conn=1011 op=0 SRCH base="" scope=0 deref=0 filter="(objectClass=*)"
Oct 17 23:44:40 debian slapd[674]: conn=1011 op=0 SEARCH RESULT tag=101 err=0 nentries=1 text=
Oct 17 23:44:40 debian slapd[674]: conn=1011 fd=14 closed (connection lost)
```

How they can search without a bind (not even an anonymous bind)? How looks the ldapsearch command?

---

The olcAccess rules of the db:

```
olcAccess: {0}to attrs=userPassword by self write by anonymous auth by * none
olcAccess: {1}to * by self write
olcAccess: {2}to * by self read
olcAccess: {3}to * by * none
```

---

If I try it with ldapsearch, I'm not able to reproduce this and it will look like this:

`ldapsearch -x` is producing the following log:

```
Oct 30 18:44:30 debian slapd[620]: conn=1006 fd=14 ACCEPT from IP=______________ (IP=[::]:389)
Oct 30 18:44:30 debian slapd[620]: conn=1006 op=0 BIND dn="" method=128
Oct 30 18:44:30 debian slapd[620]: conn=1006 op=0 RESULT tag=97 err=0 text=
Oct 30 18:44:30 debian slapd[620]: conn=1006 op=1 SRCH base="" scope=2 deref=0 filter="(objectClass=*)"
Oct 30 18:44:30 debian slapd[620]: conn=1006 op=1 SEARCH RESULT tag=101 err=32 nentries=0 text=
Oct 30 18:44:30 debian slapd[620]: conn=1006 op=2 UNBIND
Oct 30 18:44:30 debian slapd[620]: conn=1006 fd=14 closed
```

Comment: But it doesn't look like they were successfully able to search for anything?

Comment: @pgoetz It is a successful search. The closest you can get to it with `ldapsearch` is `ldapsearch -x -b '' -s base '*' +`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't believe `ldapsearch` can exhibit this behavior as it always wants to issue some sort of bind, but that isn't to say that the behavior cannot occur. The following program yields the same form of logs as you have provided.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import ldap
ldapURI = "ldap://ldap.example.com/"
ldapConnection = ldap.initialize(ldapURI)
ldapConnection.search_s('',ldap.SCOPE_BASE)
```

---

If you're looking to limit even these sorts of searches, you may be able to do so by applying olcAccess rules to `olcDatabase={-1}frontend,cn=config`. Proceed with caution before doing so.